# How to know about multiplexed inputs/outputs

Tags: microprocessor

I am working on AM3352 processor, and i need to know, which of the input/output pins are multiplexed. How to do this using datasheet, it may sound simple thing, but i am new to the  processors. Please Help.

[Link to datasheet of AM3352](http://www.ti.com/product/am3352)

Comment: A lot of this depends on what you mean by "multiplexed". From scanning the datasheet, almost all the pins can be configured as an input or an output, which is a type of multiplexing. Also, nearly all seem to have alternate functions, which is another type of multiplexing. You need to clarify your question.

Comment: Realistically, a giant BGA packaged microcontroller like that is probably a bit beyond your skill-level at this point. You are aware that that IC needs external DDR ram to work, and the traces connecting that ram will need to be impedance-controlled and length-matched, correct? You're going to need **at least** a four layer PCB (probably 6 layers, minimum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Table 2 in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/am3352).

Some of the pins have several signal names : these ones are multiplexed.

For example this pin is not multiplexed:

```
A4 DDR_WEn ddr_wen
```

and this one is

```
E18 ECAP0_IN_PWM0_OUT eCAP0_in_PWM0_out 
                      uart3_txd 
                      spi1_cs1 
                      pr1_ecap0_ecap_capin_apwm_o 
                      spi1_sclk 
                      mmc0_sdwp 
                      xdma_event_intr2
                      gpio0_7
```